# Get real requestURI without appended index.xhtml when welcome file is used

Tags: jsf, servlets, jboss, welcome-file

So here are 2 requests:

1. http://example.com/someUrl/
2. http://example.com/someUrl/index.xhtml (xhtml extension is not relevant just an example)

When the `<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>` is been set, request 1 is handled by the server as 2.

However, in both cases the `request.getRequestURI()` returns the complete URI: `someUrl/index.xhtml`.

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) it shouldn't but in most cases it's what we want so it seems fine it does.

I'm working with JSF under JBoss Wildfly (Undertow webservice) and I don't know which one is responsible.

I don't necessarily want to change how it works but I'm looking for a way of getting the original URI as the enduser sees in browser address bar, thus without the `index.xhtml` part in case of 1.

To be more precise, I have to get the exact same URL as returned by `document.location.href` in JavaScript.

Comment: So fast! I just found out the problem was only for the welcome file but you already had it edited :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The welcome file is been displayed by a forward which is under the server's covers been performed by [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29). In that case, the original request URI is available as a request attribute with a key as identified by [`RequestDispatcher#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#FORWARD_REQUEST_URI), which is [`javax.servlet.forward.request_uri`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI).

So, this should do:

```
String originalURI = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.FORWARD_REQUEST_URI);

if (originalURI == null) {
    originalURI = request.getRequestURI();
}

// ...
```